# how to create a view using a command or results of a command in Crystal Reports

Tags: sql, view, crystal-reports

I have SQL query which I can use as a 'command' to add data to my existing table in SAP Crystal Reports 2013. However I am looking to use the command to create a View which I will like to join to my original table rather. It makes the report run faster than the former.

Therefore please can someone guide me on how to create a view in SAP 2013 either by using a SQL command or the results of an existing report?

Comment: Why not just create a View in sql from the results of the query that you already have and use that in the report. Isnt it the same??

Comment: I do not have SQL on my system. I have Toad rather.

Comment: Not sure what Toad is. but if it allows you to write queries, you can probably use it to write a view.